# Bootstrap flexbox self-align class doesn't work properly

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I'm trying to create a blog post layout by using bootstrap. I'm trying to put my blog image in left side, title in right side and author name in bottom of title. But Its doesn't work. Author text goes to right side.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0CZ5.jpg

my code is :

```
        <div class="blog">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 d-flex align-items-center">
                    <img src="images/photo/blog-1.png" alt="">
                    <h4>13 of My Favorite UI/UX Goodies</h4>
                    <p class="flex-column align-self-end">By <span>Danny Sapio</span></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create two  columns to display the information. Try this:

```
<div class="blog">
    <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-6 d-flex align-items-center">
              <img src="images/photo/blog-1.png" alt="">
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-6 d-flex align-items-center">
               <h4>13 of My Favorite UI/UX Goodies</h4>
               <p class="flex-column align-self-end">By <span>Danny Sapio</span></p>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Give that a try and see if you get the results you are looking for.